# Excel: Product ID's stored as text (example: "ABC123") causing problems with inner joins

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a Product ID column that I'm trying to do an inner join on. The problem is, the Product ID column is alphanumeric, containing both letters and numbers. Some are purely numbers as well. Examples of how the column looks below:

| Product ID |
| --- |
| ABC1234 |
| 654321 |
| B08YWX3ABC |

To keep the data in the same format, I store all values in that column as text. The only problem is, I run into an issue where one table is being inner-joined on another and getting N/A's:

| Table 1 - Product ID | Totals |
| --- | --- |
| "654321" | 12 |

| Table 2 - Product ID | Retailer |
| --- | --- |
| "654321" | ABC Company |

| Table.InnerJoin - Product ID | Retailer | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "654321" | N/A | N/A |

Here's the excel query: `= Table.NestedJoin(#"Table 1", {"Product ID"}, #"Table 2", {"Product ID"}, "product list", JoinKind.Inner)`

How can I debug this, either in Google Sheets (where the product ID's are stored) or in Excel (where the inner join is happening)?

Edit: problem solved by retyping each broken value. There was an invisible character that was introduced by copying and pasting from another source, which was not trimmable and could not be found visually nor through dtype inspection. When I retyped the ID's manually, the unique keys matched and the NA's disappeared. The original looked something like this:

[N/A's introduced by coercion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yY3N.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you have posted. Using a Nested Join I get a Table, which, when expanded, shows the desired results. *(Using a simple Table.Join, I also get the desired results.)*  Not sure how your are getting `N/A` in that column.  There is some other issue not apparent in what you have shared.

Comment: Hi Ron, I was working on this all day. What I found out was that the cells were copied by another person and placed in, and some weird character that was invisible to the eye was introduced. I trimmed the values, I checked the values as a string, and a string doesn't really show anything wrong besides extracting the value and reformatting. So I ended up retyping each broken value and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I also edited the above to show the error as it appeared on my side, to help future readers understand what it looks like.

Comment: Transform / Clean removes most (but not all) of those invisible characters. It is eternally frustrating how PQ is more fussy than regular Excel or SQL.